# Formulario no manda correos

Tags: php, html5, css3

He creado un blog con html5, css3 y php.
En la página contacto.php he puesto un formulario para que me puedan mandar un correo con un comentario, pero he hecho alguna prueba y no recibo nada. He puesto dos líneas para que me muestre si hay errores en el php y tampoco me dice que hay nada mal.
Este es el código:

```
<?php
    require_once('../includes/config.php');
    if(!$user->is_logged_in()){
        header('Location:login.php');
    }
    if(isset($_GET['delpost'])){
        $stmt=$db->prepare('DELETE FROM blog_posts WHERE postID=:postID');
        $stmt->execute(array(':postID'=>$_GET['delpost']));
        header('Location:index.php?action=deleted');
        exit;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Contacto</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/styles.css">
    <style>
        #seccion{
            background-color:#9BE8FF;
        }
        #seccion>p>a{
            font-size:20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>REAL ZARAGOZA</h1>
        <h3>... MÁS QUE UNA PASIÓN!</h3>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../index.php">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="../about.php">Sobre nosotros</a></li>
            <li><a href="../fotos.php">Fotos</a></li>
            <li><a href="contacto.php">Contacto</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Suscribete</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <aside>
            <h1>ENLACES DE INTERES</h1>
            <a href="http://realzaragoza.com">Página oficial del Real Zaragoza</a></br>
            <a href="http://aupazaragoza.com">Página de Aupa Zaragoza</a></br>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/realzaragoza">Real Zaragoza en Twitter</a></br>
            <a href="https://es-es.facebook.com/RealZaragozaOficial">Real Zaragoza en Facebook</a></br>
            <a href="https://instagram.com/realzaragoza">Real Zaragoza en Instagram</a></br>
            <a href="https://heraldo.es/noticias/deportes/futbol/real_zaragoza/portada">Heraldo de Aragón</a></br>
            <a href="http://elperiodicodearagon.com/noticias/realzaragoza">El Periódico de Aragón</a></br>
            <h1>PATROCINADORES</h1>
            <a align="middle" class="foto" href="https://adidas.es" target="_blank"><img src="../images/adidas.png" alt="ADIDAS" border="0"></a></br>
            <a align="middle" class="foto" href="https://jamoneseutiquio.com" target="_blank"><img src="../images/eutiquio.jpg" alt="JAMONES EUTIQUIO" border="0"></a></br>
            <a align="middle" class="foto" href="https://caixabank.es/particular/home/particulares_es.html" target="_blank"><img src="../images/caixabank.jpg" alt="CAIXABANK" border="0"></a></br>
            <a align="middle" class="foto" href="https://movistar.es" target="_blank"><img src="../images/movistar.jpg" alt="MOVISTAR" border="0"></a></br>
        </aside>
        <section id="seccion">
            <?php include('menu.php');?>
            <form id="ContactForm" method="post" action="">
                <p><label>Nombre: </label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" value=""></p>
                <p><label>Email: </label><br/>
                <input type="text" name ="email" value=""></p>
                <p><label>Asunto: </label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="asunto" value=""></p>
                <p><label>Mensaje: </label><br/>
                <textarea name="mensaje" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea></p>
                <p><input type="submit" name='submit' value="Enviar"></p>  
            </form>
            <?php
                error_reporting(E_ALL);
                ini_set('display_errors', '1');
                if(isset($_POST["nombre"]) and isset($_POST["correo"])){
                    $destino="cdum77@gmail.com";
                    $asunto="Real Zaragoza";
                    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
                    $email=$_POST['email'];
                    $asunto=$_POST['asunto'];
                    $mensaje=$_POST['mensaje'];
                    $msn="
                        Nombre: $nombre \n
                        email: $email \n
                        asunto: $asunto \n
                        mensaje: $mensaje \n
                    ";
                    $cabeceras='From: cdum77@gmail.com'."\r\n".'Reply-To: cdum77@gmail.com'."\r\n".'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();
                    if(mail($destino,$asunto,$msn,$cabeceras)){
                        header("Location:contacto.php?m=1");
                        //echo "SE envio";
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <p>© 2018 Charly Utrilla</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Podríamos ver el código del formulario de contacto, y el script del backend que envía el correo?

Comment: Si esta entrando a tu condición `if(isset($_POST["nombre"]) and isset($_POST["correo"])){` ?

Comment: lo siento, pero sigo sin resolver el problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fíjate que tienes un error en el primer "if":

```
if(isset($_POST["nombre"]) and isset($_POST["correo"])){
```

Debería ser:

```
if(isset($_POST["nombre"]) and isset($_POST["email"])){
```

Comment: bien visto Jose Carlos, pero todavia no funciona

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he arreglado.
Además de tener algunas partes del código mal, no tenía bien configurado Mercury, ni tampoco el archivo php.ini.
Ahora ya me funciona bien.
Gracias a todos.

P. D.: si alguien más lo necesita en esta página está todo bien detallado de qué y cómo hay que hacer para enviar correos desde localhost a una dirección de correo externa (gmail) con smtp:
http://www.medisoft.cl/configurar-mercury-xampp-para-enviar-correos-desde-localhost/

Comment: Ok, me alegro lo hayas solucionado.